# What is a Venomous Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Venomous Word™**.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Venomous Words™ | Not Venomous Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| ABBREVIATED | EXPANDED |
| BABYSITTER | KIDNAPPER |
| BRAINTEASER | RIDDLE |
| CROSSHATCHING | COLORING |
| FABRICATE | MANUFACTURE |
| INEBRIATED | SOBER |
| OBITUARIES | EULOGIES |
| OBSCENITIES | NICETIES |
| STAINED-GLASS | ARTWORK |
| SUBDIRECTORIES | HIERARCHY |
| SUBORDINATE | SUPERVISOR |
| SUBSISTENCE | DELICIOUSNESS |
| WAINSCOTING | PANELING |
| BIOSYNTHESIZING* | BIOENGINEERING |

*<sup>* Exceedingly venomous</sup>*

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Venomous Words™,Not Venomous Words™
ABBREVIATED,EXPANDED
BABYSITTER,KIDNAPPER
BRAINTEASER,RIDDLE
CROSSHATCHING,COLORING
FABRICATE,MANUFACTURE
INEBRIATED,SOBER
OBITUARIES,EULOGIES
OBSCENITIES,NICETIES
STAINED-GLASS,ARTWORK
SUBDIRECTORIES,HIERARCHY
SUBORDINATE,SUPERVISOR
SUBSISTENCE,DELICIOUSNESS
WAINSCOTING,PANELING
BIOSYNTHESIZING,BIOENGINEERING
```

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Venomous Word™ without relying on the other words.
These are not the only examples of Venomous Words™; many more exist.

> **What is the special rule these words conform to?**

Comment: Yes! Another one :)

Comment: Is hierarchy misspelled purposely?

Comment: @JamesWebster Nope. It's either because spell check didn't catch it OR because my running spell check was just a fever dream and didn't actually happen. I'll fix it soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The answer:

> Venomous words have this property: you can remove letters and result in the letters `B-I-T-E` or `S-T-I-N-G` in order.  `BIOSYNTHESIZING` can result in *either* of these two venom-related strings.